# Building a very small scale, but multithreaded and distributed search engine

Tags: java, multithreading, search-engine

We(group of 5) have taken up above mentioned project for our present semester. We have an overview of how a search engine works..and we started off by learning building a web crawler using JAVA language. I wanted to know what could be the technologies/ programming languages that i would require in the course of building this project.

1. Are there any already available API's or packages that i cud use
   instead of hard coding every single stuff.Like there is one LUCENE
   package(built on java) that provides efficient text search
   algorithms which we could use i guess.
2. What would be the most suitable programming language to work with,
   java/python/c++ or any other?

Comment: Never seen a python compiler...
Also, you definately need a database architecture to store your search index / cache (Or infinite amounts of RAM lol)

Comment: At least this question mustn't be downvoted. He must be helped by experienced professionals...

Comment: @AlexR-Why are you bothering about infinite RAM,LOL??? He will perform it on a small scale,if you know what I mean. He is not creating Google-Search-Engine!

Comment: @AlexR-Yeah we are doing it for learning purpose mainly... We have sufficient systems at our disposal in our lab so that won't be an issue considering the small-scale project.

Comment: @shekharsuman wait, what? He *MUST BE HELPED* ? Then pay for the help of such professionals.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun- Why so rude??? His question showed genuine interest and was seeking for a genuine help! I expect someone to come and answer as I am inexperienced to answer this!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my two cents. If your project is to build a search engine ground up, consider looking at the paper by Page and Brin (http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html). Ofcourse the same is not used now by Google but the basis remains similar. If you are using Lucene, all you need to do is create the frontend. But if you plan on making everything on your own, you need to consider how would you rank a page, how often would you update your indexes and how would you store them. Note that today's web contains not only textual data, there are videos, tweets, images and other forms of media. Consider formulating a plan for them. Like any search engine, your priority should be fast lookup and that would depend on how your indexes are stored and retrieved. Another priority is showing up the results in a particular format. Consider formulating a plan for that like would it based on the number of backlinks, freshness, etc.